# Cakephp 2.0 change password

Tags: cakephp

I am attempting to create a change password form in cakephp 2.0.  I found a behavior that EuroMark created for 1.3 and now am having a tough time converting this code to work with 2.0. I know that it has something to do with the Auth Component as there were major changes to this component in 2.0.

```
public function validateCurrentPwd(Model $Model, $data) {
if (is_array($data)) {
    $pwd = array_shift($data);
} else {
    $pwd = $data;
}

$uid = null;
if ($Model->id) {
    $uid = $Model->id;
} elseif (!empty($Model->data[$Model->alias]['id'])) {
    $uid = $Model->data[$Model->alias]['id'];
} else {
    return false;
}

if (class_exists('AuthExtComponent')) {
    $this->Auth = new AuthExtComponent();
} elseif (class_exists($this->settings[$Model->alias]['auth'].'Component')) {
    $auth = $this->settings[$Model->alias]['auth'].'Component';
    $this->Auth = new $auth();
} else {
    return true;
}
return $this->Auth->verifyUser($uid, $pwd);
}
```

I am getting an error on the line that reads $this->Auth = new $auth();
The error is as follows:

```
Argument 1 passed to Component::__construct() must be an instance of ComponentCollection, none given, called in C:\UniServer\www\new_company_test\app\Model\Behavior\change_password.php on line 117 and defined [CORE\Cake\Controller\Component.php, line 77]
```

and

```
Undefined variable: collection [CORE\Cake\Controller\Component.php, line 78]
```

it's also throwing this

```
Call to undefined method AuthComponent::verifyUser() in C:\UniServer\www\new_company_test\app\Model\Behavior\change_password.php on line 121
```

I am not sure if there is anything else that needs to be addressed in the script, I'm guessing not as there is no other place where Auth is used.

Any suggestions on what I need to do to get this to work? Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I currently work on a clean 2.0 rewrite of the "current pwd" feature (had to be pretty hacky for 1.3). will post it here as soon as i am done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you did discover that there is also a 2.0 branch, didnt you? :)
it should contain the same behavior:
https://github.com/dereuromark/tools/tree/2.0

either way, you need to pass a component collection into it:

```
$this->Auth = new AuthExtComponent(new ComponentCollection());
```

You should create a method `verifyUser` in your custom AuthExt Component which extends Auth Component for "current password" to work like so:

```
/**
 * Quickfix
 * TODO: improve - maybe use Authenticate
 * @return bool $success
 */
public function verifyUser($id, $pwd) {
    $options = array(
        'conditions' => array('id'=>$id, 'password'=>$this->password($pwd)),
    );
    return $this->getModel()->find('first', $options);

    $this->constructAuthenticate();
    $this->request->data['User']['password'] = $pwd;
    return $this->identify($this->request, $this->response);
}

/**
 * returns the current User model
 * @return object $User
 */
public function getModel() {
    return ClassRegistry::init(CLASS_USER); 
}
```

Maybe it is also possible to use the existing `identify` method in combination with a fake request object in the behavior directly?
I am thinking about using

```
$this->authenticate = array('Form'=>array('fields'=>array('username' => 'id')));
```

feel free to fork the behavior and submit a pull request.

"current password" is the only thing that is not yet cleanly solved right now.

Comment: Thank you euromark this has been helpful.  I am still getting the error for the verifyUser() from above. When I look into the AuthComponent I do not see this function. Is it something that I need to add somewhere? I see what it is suppose to do, but don't know where this function is to perform the it.

Comment: you are right. It is missing (I added it for my custom AuthComponent). I wasnt sure how to proceed here without breaking too much MVC - since Auth is a component which should normally not be used in a behavioral context^^. So if you come up with a better idea let me know.

Comment: Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous

SQL Query: SELECT `USER`.`id`, `USER`.`username`, `USER`.`password`, `USER`.`name`, `USER`.`phone`, `USER`.`fax`, `USER`.`department_id`, `USER`.`email`, `USER`.`group_email`, `USER`.`job_title`, `USER`.`initials`, `Department`.`id`, `Department`.`name` FROM `users` AS `USER` LEFT JOIN `departments` AS `Department` ON (`USER`.`department_id` = `Department`.`id`) WHERE `id` = 1 AND `password` = '7174f42511db0855479274fed73744febb099121' LIMIT 1 

how do I make it so id is user.id?

Comment: One more thing, this comes up when I use the save($this->request->data). If I use saveField or save($this->request->data, true, password) I don't get this error.  And when I use either of these last two methods validation does not work.  Why is there a select statement with the save method? And why does validation not work when using either of the other 2 ways of doing this? Thanks for all your help with this.

Comment: got it! :) after realizing how 2.0 auth works I figured out a clean way to authenticate with id + pwd. check out the current head. your problems shoudl be fixed now.

Comment: wow, thank you, it works like a charm. Glad to get this done.

Comment: One last thing, I change my password and when I go to log in with the new password in does not log me in. Does this have something to do with the hashType or hashSalt variables in the settings?  How do I know what my new password is?

Comment: how is it saved? as a hash or plain text?

Comment: It's saving it as a hash, at least that is what it looks like in the database.

Comment: well, it works perfect for me. my guess is that sth else is responsible here. but I cant be sure, of course.

Comment: is it possible that the password is being hashed 2 times? Once in the behavior and once in my beforeSave in my model? I ask because when I create a new user the password is hashed and when I change my password to the same as that of the user I just created the 2 hashes are different in the database. If this is the case is there a better way to hash the password upon creation of a new user?

Comment: well, you shouldnt have been hashing it in your model in the first place ;) thats what this behavior is for, after all. did you read the article with the examples? http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/08/25/working-with-passwords-in-cakephp/